# Error Code 1064 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a problem with a Trigger and a Procedure in MySQL, the exercises track is:

*Define a Trigger that delete automatically visits of patients that in the last year they did only the preliminer visit.*

This is the SQL code created from me:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EliminaVisitePreliminari
AFTER INSERT ON Visita
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(
        SELECT Vis.ID_Visita
        FROM Visita AS Vis, Preliminare AS Pre
        WHERE Vis.ID_Visita=Pre.ID_Visita
        AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), Vis.Data)>365
        GROUP BY Vis.ID_Visita)) THEN
            DELETE FROM Visita
            WHERE ID_Visita=(
                SELECT Vis.ID_Visita
                FROM Visita AS Vis1, Preliminare AS Pre1
                WHERE Vis1.ID_Visita=Pre1.ID_Visita
                AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), Vis.Data)>365
            ); # Error here
    END IF; # Here
END; # And here
```

And this for Procedure:

*Define a schedulated procedure that, every ending's month, calculates automatically the amount of every month's interventions, showing the percentage not yet sold*

SQL created from me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TotInterventiSettimanali(OUT Cont INT, SomTot INT, Saldare DECIMAL)
BEGIN
DECLARE Costo INT; # Error here
DECLARE DaSald DECIMAL; # Here
DECLARE Cont INT; # Here

SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(Vis.Parcella), AVG(Vis.Parcella) INTO Cont, SomTot, Saldare
FROM Visita AS Vis, Intervento AS Inerv
WHERE MONTH(Vis.Data)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND Vis.ID_Visita=Interv.ID_Visita;

END; # And here
```

Help me please.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: For a Trigger and a Procedure, I insert the code and the exercises track in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL treats everything ending with ";" as command. To create functions, procedures and triggers, you have to change the delimiter to something else, input the text and change the delimiter back. For example, in your case:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE TotInterventiSettimanali(OUT Cont INT, SomTot INT, Saldare DECIMAL)
BEGIN
.......
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note the delimiter `//` after procedure text.

Comment: As I said, try the same with a trigger :)